# Listen to YouTube on Firefox in the background

Tags: youtube, firefox-for-android

[On some pages](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/quick-tip-use-firefox-play-youtube-videos-background-0173597/) I found the advice, that I could let YouTube videos play in the background when using Firefox for Android. And it works with the video in the article, but not on YouTube.com. Unlike suggested [in this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5ruwrq/android_youtube_pause_on_tab_switch/), it also happens on Firefox beta and is not connected to the bug referenced there.

Is this a restriction by YouTube and if, is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: Check this article to fix it: [Fix Firefox's YouTube Background Playback Feature on Android](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/fix-firefoxs-youtube-background-playback-feature-android-0177764/) (I found this related news from the page shared in the question.) I use Firefox Beta and for me it works perfectly.